# How to convert pandas DataFrame to a specific json format

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe in this format :

```
DataProvider,Id,Name,Time

ABC,f8453e99-516f-4f15-a3bd-8749089b6934,"xyz",43200

ABC,f8453e99-516f-4f15-a3bd-8749089b6934,"123",43200

ABC,00453e99-516f-4f15-a3bd-8749089b6934,"xyz",43200
```

I want to generate the output in this format (json) :

```
  {
  "dataProviderId":"ABC",
  "items": [
    {
    "Id":"f8453e99-516f-4f15-a3bd-8749089b6934",
    "data": [
      {"Name":"xyz","Time":43200},
      {"Name":"xyz","Time":43200}
    ],
    },
    {
    "Id":"00453e99-516f-4f15-a3bd-8749089b6934",
    "data": [
        {"Name":"xyz","Time":43200}
    ]
    }
```

---

This is what I have tried so far. I am trying to group by "Name" and "Time" fields first to a dictionary and then call it "data". After that I will do one more group by and aggregate "data" and "Id" and call it "items".
After that, I think, I can download the results to the required json format using df.to_json()

This is the code so far :

```
import pandas as pd
import os

df = pd.read_csv('bq-results-20200320-121645-a47v3t1cq9op.csv',encoding='UTF-8')

output = (df.groupby(['dataProviderId', 'Id'], as_index=False)
     .apply(lambda x: dict(zip(['Name','Time''],x[['Name','Time']]))).reset_index(name='data'))
```

However, this is the output that I get :

```
    dataProviderId  Id  data
0   lifesight   0016b4a4-c807-497f-b86d-eec8bd53f11f    {'Name': 'Name', 'Time': 'Time'}
1   lifesight   0057eb21-93f7-4818-af15-871a5f131006    {'Name': 'Name', 'Time': 'Time'}
2   lifesight   00b86381-c697-496b-b45f-334fc1247914    {'Name': 'Name', 'Time': 'Time'}
3   lifesight   0163b87e-f59b-4fc5-8c2e-78cb17b47404    {'Name': 'Name', 'Time': 'Time'}
4   lifesight   01c5d810-18b9-425a-bc2a-03bac44f675f    {'Name': 'Name', 'Time': 'Time'
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, nor is it meant to provide personalized guides and tutorials. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: Hi Ankur. I have just edited the post and added the steps that I have done so far in the post.